# Runtime EF connection for Database on Pendrive

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

We have a WPF desktop application using EF5 and SQL Server LocalDB on a pendrive.

We want to select a database during application startup. Since the drive (`H:` / `G:`) for the pendrive is not fixed, so we can not hard-code it or save in a config file.

How can we make the runtime connection in such situation?

Comment: Is it in a fixed location on that drive? You could scan all drives. Where is your application running?

Answer (score 1):

Get application path using `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` and then get the drive letter, eventually by making a match with all drives that exists on that computer ( you can use [DriveInfo.GetDrives()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.getdrives%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method ).